# How to stop time counter at 00 in php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, time

I'm trying to make time counter it's working fine but it does not stop at 00:00:00 and goes back to 24:00:00.
Here is my code.

```
<?php

session_start();
$from_time1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$to_time1 = $_SESSION['end_time'];
$timefirst = strtotime($from_time1);
$timesecond = strtotime($to_time1);

$difference = $timesecond-$timefirst;
echo gmdate("H:i:s",$difference);
?>
```

Comment: Try with an if?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $from_time1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   $to_time1 = $_SESSION['end_time'];
   $timefirst = strtotime($from_time1);
   $timesecond = strtotime($to_time1);

   $difference = $timesecond-$timefirst;

   $diff= gmdate("H:i:s",$difference);
   if($diff == '00:00:00'){
   //stop the timer logic
   }else{
     echo $diff;
   }

?>
```

You can try this